# How to configure Aspectj for Eclipse

Tags: aop

I am trying to configure Aspectj in eclipse but its not working can someone please share the full configuration of aspectj. I also explored different tutorials but of no use if some one has usefull stuff regarding this please share.

Can i download the eclipse ide having builtin support for Aspectj

Comment: Which Eclipse version? Which AJDT version? Which download URL? It is kinda hard to help if you do not give us any information. Please update the question, it is way too general.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Eclipse comes bundled with AspectJ. You can download it here:

http://eclipse.org/ajdt/downloads/

Install it as you would any other Eclipse plugin, e.g. via *Help -> Install New Software* (in Eclipse 3.7.1).

http://eclipse.org/ajdt/gettingstarted.php

[image: Screenshot of Install Software]

Once installed, you can create AspectJ projects using the *New -> Project* menu.

[image: New AspectJ Project]

Now you will have an AspectJ project that you can write aspects (`.aj` files) in.

http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-aspectj.html#aspects

Comment: I have tried the same but i am getting an error "unable to connect to repository"

Comment: So you can't install the plugin? Are you behind a firewall? Is the proxy settings for Eclipse configured?